# IE 11 open in multi tabs perfomance issue

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, dom, web

The application that was written base on web api + angular 5. 
Test page size is about ~5 mb (~5 request) at IE 11 (picture snippet below)

[image]

I ought to open similar or ever same page at 10 separate tabs. It works at Google Chrome and Firefox, but IE stop processing after 5-th or 6-th tab (without any error message).

**Q:**

- Are there any ideas how I can work around it?
- what could be the reason?
- Has Ie 11 some memory limit if so how I can extent it?

When i use prod build mode Ie load 7-8 tabs, but not 10

Thanks at advance

Comment: better to use edge.

Comment: i agree with you, but i really have to use ie 11)

Comment: @Jai IE11 is still in active development, and widely used in the industrial world. A pity that we have to deal with those people that don't want to upgrade :-/

Comment: Is this a production version of your app? Build with `ng build --prod`, or are you opening the `ng serve` version in IE11?

Comment: i run at develop mode, i will try at production mode

Comment: i lodad at prod, it had possitive effect but it coudn't load 10 tabs