# How to open tabs in new process at ie 11 throught javascript or ie settings

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web

IE has **memory limitation** of memory consumption **at one process**, so if we want to open a lot 'heavy' pages (each at seperate tab) we will get non-working browser.

**Q:** Is there any approache to open internet explorer tabs in seperate process (as it did chrome e.g) throught javascript or ie settings?

P.s it questation relates to my previous question [IE 11 open in multi tabs perfomance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652170/ie-11-open-in-multi-tabs-perfomance-issue)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/586622/force-ie-to-use-one-process-per-tab

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for it weren't the system registry it would be perfect. I would like to find some approache with javascript or at least ie browser settings.

Comment: You can't control how the browser behaves, from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promblem was solved though click simulation. This approache allows run each tab in separate process.

```
 const link = this.windowRefService.nativeWindow.document.getElementById('navigator');
            link.setAttribute('href', url);
            link.click();
```